# Suggestion: Required tag for tradition

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to suggest a required tag on all new posts to indicate the tradition being asked about, or `none`/`any`/whatever wording you like. This would save time on back-and-forth info-gathering for questions, as well as filtering and searching by tradition. For example if I'm a new Buddhist looking for information on the precepts, I'm confronted with 36 pages of results; if I can be sure that filtering by `[mahayana]` will get me results that make sense given my location/local temple/whatever, that would be helpful. Another example would be questions that mix Pali and Sanskrit, or questions that could be answered by any school, but the asker was really looking for a specific perspective.

I think it would also be useful to set a limit on granularity, unless the Buddhism SE grows significantly. Meaning, maybe only `mahayana`, `theravada`, `vajrayana`, `secular-buddhism`, and an unknown/any type of tag would be required-tags, not something like `thai-forest`, `chan`, `gelugpa`, etc.

Related questions and answers: [dealing with different traditions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50/19522), specifically the last section of this answer; [this one on a possible schism on the site](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2234/19522), [this one](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/i-think-the-community-should-use-the-theravada-mahayana-tag-more-if-they-dont-w) about trying to enforce tag usage, and [the fact that this feature apparently exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/show-required-tags-when-asking-a-question-on-meta) (I don't know how it works on the moderator side, but the [API also lists required tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags#order=desc&sort=popular&filter=default&site=buddhism&run=true), and this Meta SE has them, so the feature seems to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for caring enough to suggest an improvement.

I found this -- it's old, but so far as I know it is still up-to-date (I asked with no answer to the contrary):

- [Can meta-style 'required tags' be implemented on non-meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195184/can-meta-style-required-tags-be-implemented-on-non-meta-sites)

In summary it says that:

- Yes, it can be configured
- No, it never is
- It would have to be the SE team that configures it, not moderators -- and they wouldn't, so don't ask
- There are reasons why it's not a good idea

So I can't do it, and I don't think they would do it if I asked.

As for whether it's a good idea, I don't know.

- Some questions may not don't fit neatly
- Some people asking questions may not know enough or care to specify one tradition

We currently use those as optional tags:

- If it's specified, the user only wants answers from within that tradition, and other answers to that question would be off-topic (deleted)
- If it's not specified, then answers from any tradition are welcomed

I think that works quite well, usually, at least for beginners like me.

And if you want to limit the replies when you ask a new question, you can already.

That doesn't solve the problem of filtering or sorting already-posted answers. When I first joined this site I went through all the meta-posts, to re-tag them, make some sense of their tags -- but even then (several years ago) I didn't try to do that to the posts on the main site -- too big a job and not one I think I could do well (i.e. both thoroughly and accurately).

Comment: Fair enough! I'm not a moderator on any StackExchange so I've never seen the tools page, and didn't realize that change would have to come from the actual SE staff. A default value of "any" would solve the "I don't want to choose a sect" problem, but as far as I can tell that functionality also doesn't exist (even for meta sites). I'll trust your judgement that it's not a great idea to pursue.